# Name resolution for a Windows server with 2 NICS

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

I have a Windows 2003 server with 2 NICS: first one is connected to production lan, second to administration lan. This server is also joined to domain and listed on DNS. So it has two IP addresses.

Is it correct to have two different DNS A records (two different DNS names) on DNS, one for the first IP and the second for the other IP? I feel it would be more correct to have one IP associated to an A record, and the second IP associated to an alias (CNAME).

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not correct as far as I'm concerned. What would be your reason for having a CNAME?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need the two IPs to be resolved with the same name. May be I did some confusion :-(

Comment: That's going to create problems.